# Python Simplifying an 'If' Statement

Tags: python, string, if-statement, integer

I have the following rather simple if statement in Python 3.3.4, it works as it is but surly it can be simplified:

```
if ans is '1':
    ans = int(ans)
    ans = (opt[ans])
elif ans is '2':
    ans = int(ans)
    ans = (opt[ans])
elif ans is '3':
    ans = int(ans)
    ans = (opt[ans])
```

I have tried various combinations of this:

```
if ans is '1' or '2' or '3':
    ans = int(ans)
    ans = (opt[ans])
```

or this,

```
if ans == '1' or '2' or '3':
    ans = int(ans)
    ans = (opt[ans])
```

or this,

```
if ans is ('1') or ('2') or ('3'):
    ans = int(ans)
    ans = (opt[ans])
```

I have even tried using dictionaries but most combinations will just allow through any string for 'ans'; am I being silly and missing something really simple or is this not possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: PLEASE, `is` is not the same as `==`.  You should be using `==` in this case.  You will almost never need to use `is`, please forget it exists.  You will get results you cannot explain and do not expect if you continue to use `is` in place of `==`.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, I am rather new to Python. What about 'in' or '!='? is this a similar situation?

Comment: No.  There is no situation where you could replace `is` or `==` with `in`, so there is no chance of getting it confused with `is` or `==`.  `!=` is just the logical opposite of `==`.

Comment: No that's what I meant, should I use one or the other in a majority of cases, 'in' or '!='? I don't mean to replace '==' or 'is', I know they are the opposite.

Comment: I'm confused.  `in` and `!=` mean totally different things.  `in` means "is some thing inside this list/dict/tuple/container"? `!=` means "not equal".  `==` means "equal".  `is` means "the object IDs are equal".  What I was trying to say is that there are 0 cases where it would be even syntactically valid to switch `in` for `!=` or vice versa, let alone logically valid.  I don't understand the origin of your question.

Comment: Also, `is` and `==` are not opposite... they do different things.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, you answered my very poorly worded question in the previous comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if ans in ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly; I was being stupid!

Comment: Yes, I just had to wait 4 minutes or it wouldn't let me.